# How to hold memory allocated by kmalloc even it is freed by other function

Tags: c, linux, linux-kernel, network-programming, linux-device-driver

I have a situation where memory allocated by `kmalloc` should not be freed even some other part of the linux kernel calls `kfree` on it. Below is the scenario:

1. My driver allocate memory using `kmalloc()` and creates `skb` using that buffer.
2. Driver passes this skb to the network stack.
3. Network stack processes the packet and calls free on the buffer which is allocated by driver.
4. But driver want to reuse the same buffer for upcoming packets.

Is there any way to achieve this? I know we can use pages by using page count but i cannot use pages. I have to use kmalloc.

Comment: Like with malloc/free this is not possible, since there is no such thing as reference counters for these kind of memory blocks. Either copy it or use other kernel functions, which do not free the buffer, if possible

Comment: I think this is not possible kmalloc , but there is memblock_reserve concept in Linux kernel, In which you reserve memory at boot up, no body will  free this memory until you explicitly wants, but you want you kmalloc :(

Comment: Umm.. have the network stack processes the packet and not calling free on the buffer if there is space in a local buffer pool to save it for later use.

Comment: easy way could be allocate another local buffer and copy to this buffer before passing to upper layer.